# C++17 - Return multiple values from function into already declared variables

Tags: c++, return-value, return-type

With C++17 you can return multiple values from a function something like this:

```
struct SomeStruct{int a, b;};

SomeStruct getSomeStruct() {return SomeStruct();}

//...

auto [a,b] = getSomeStruct();
```

Can you return multiple values like this into already declared variables?

This will not work:

```
int a, b;
[a,b] = getSomeStruct();
```

Comment: I think [std::tie](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) may be what you want (requires returning `std::tuple`)

Comment: You can but in python. Here you need a bit more code to accomplish what you need.